# Repeat a string N times with while loop in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have just started C++ and I am having difficulties with the `while` loop.

Here are the instructions:
Change the classic Hello World program:
so that the program prints `N` times the "HelloWorld" string (on separate lines),
with `N` entered by the user.
Tips:

- Use `cin >>` to acquire `N`.
- Use a `WHILE` loop with a counter variable to handle repetitions.
- Be careful to use `cout <<` with `"\ n"` or `endl` for bounce back.

And here is my code; I don't know what to put in the while loop to print the Hello World string `N` times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Variabili 
  int n;
  cout<<"Inserisci il numero di volte che vuoi ripetere la stringa Hello World!:";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<"Hai deciso di ripetere la stringa"<<" "<<n<<" "<<"volte";

  // Ciclo While che ripete la stringa n volte
  while()
  {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  }
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(n > 0)
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
n--;
}`

Comment: Do you know what, in general, i.e. abstractly, should go into the `()` and into the `{}` of a `while`? I recommend to try understanding that, before using the code-only answer in the comment by @GauravPathak.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes i know what should go in them, like the condition in () and then the action in {} but i don't know how to adapt them in base of instructions.

Comment: I do not really get your meaning "in base of instructions".

Comment: Have you seen any working `while(...){...}` in your studies until now? Did  you work through a tutorial on loops?

Comment: The trick is to do something inside `{...}` which changes the true/false of the condition inside `(...)`. (It can be "hidden" inside the condition expression itself, but I recommend not to do so.)

Answer (score 2):

Think about a while in the following way:

```
while(condition){
  BODY;
}
```

keep executing `BODY` until `condition` is true.
As an example, when it rains, you usually keep your umbrella open while it is raining. When the condition *is raining* is not true anymore you put the umbrella away, right?

```
    while(isRaining){
       holdUmbrella();
    } 
    closeUmbrella();
```

The condition for your case is, **keep writing until I have written "Hello World" less than** `N` **times**. So the idea is to count the number of times you print. In order to do this, you can use a counter that is incremented each time you print. The condition of the while checks that the counter is not grater than `N`. Something like the following should work.

```
int counter=0;
while(counter<N)
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
   //remember that you printed one time more. increment counter
    counter=counter+1;
}
```

Comment: I like your style of answering. But I think the umbrella example is more confusing than helpful. I would handle the open umbrella more like `while(raining){} CloseUmbrella();`; which admittedly is even more confusing code for explaining the loop.

Comment: Nice rain handler now. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The "while" instruction basically execute a piece of code into {} while the test in () is true.

```
while(TEST)
{
    // any code you want to repeat while TEST is true
}
```

When your program hit the "while" instruction it will evaluate the TEST and if the TEST is true then it will run the code contain in the brackets. Once the program reach the last instruction in the brackets it will go back to the top of the "while" and evaluate TEST again. This process will repeat as long as TEST is true.

In your example you want the code to execute 10 times so you could create a counter variable and increment by one every time you print the text "hello world" like so:

```
int count = 0;
while(count < n)// this is true while count is inferior to n
{
     printf("hello world!");
     count++; // count = count + 1; 
     // count will progressively take the value 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10
     // since 10 is equal to n (10) then the TEST (10 < 10) will return false and the "while" instruction will stop there
     // printing will not happen for count == n (10) but it will for 0, for a total of n times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **while** loop is a control flow statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given Boolean condition.The while loop can be thought of as a repeating if statement.

**Syntax:** `while(condition){ execute this }`

The code inside while loop is executed till the condition is true.

**Flowchart:**

[image]

In the above problem, Since you want to console out Hello World!  ***N*** times, `while(N--)` will work.

**Sample Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    while(N--)
        cout<<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

***Note:*** The statement `cout<<"Hello World!\n"` executes till ***N>=0***.